# page does not refresh when using angular ui router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-router, sails.js

Backend Framework - [Sails.js](http://sailsjs.com/)

Frontend Framework - Angular.js ver 1.5.8 with Angular-UI-router ver 1.0.3

login/Register screen ---> After response from backend state.transitionTo() Dashboard

When I refresh the page before registering, login and signup refresh well.
But, after login when I refresh them, they don't refresh properly. they go to infinite refresh

**Config Code :**

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("client/login")

    $stateProvider.state('app/dashboard', {
        url: '/app/dashboard',
        templateUrl: 'templates/client/index.html',
        controller: 'ClientMasterCtrl'
    }).state('login', {
        url: '/client/login',
        templateUrl: 'templates/client/login.html',
        controller: 'ClientLoginCtrl'
    }).state('register', {
        url: '/client/register',
        templateUrl: 'templates/client/register.html',
        controller: 'ClientRegisterCtrl'
    });
```

**Login / Register Transition Code :**

```
.success(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                $state.transitionTo('app/dashboard');
            });
```

Unable to find any way.
could someone help me or point me in right direction
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try changing success to then as the former is deprecated in new versions of angularjs. and also you can do $location.path('app/dashboard') after you inject $location in your controller

Comment: @Vivz Unable to Work as its still in infinite loop

Comment: Quick tip: name states using dots not slashes, so your state should be named `app.dashboard` only the url you use `app/dashboard`.

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro For him to do that, don't he need a parent state app ?

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro Thank you Already change app/dashboard to dashboard after Vivz reply

Comment: Are you getting any errors in console?

Comment: Than also change `$state.transitionTo('app/dashboard'); ` to `$state.transitionTo('dashboard');`

Comment: As @Vivz pointed out, the `.success()` method is deprecated, use `.then()` instead. Also, about your infinite loop, is there any possibility the dashboard page is redirecting back to login?

Comment: Also, give a try on `$state.go('dashboard')`, the method is more a appropriated in most cases. Or this for casting errors: `$state.go('dashboard').then(console.log, console.error)`

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro yes i have change it back to $state.transitionTo('dashboard'); and working on then() method and $state.go() thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$state.go('app/dashboard')` [Documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options).

For $state.transitionTo this is a [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/eXR0lbhHevFpDfiwCr6D?p=preview)

> Convenience method for transitioning to a new state. $state.go calls
>   $state.transitionTo internally but automatically sets options to {
>   location: true, inherit: true, relative: $state.$current, notify: true
>   }. This allows you to easily use an absolute or relative to path and
>   specify only the parameters you'd like to update (while letting
>   unspecified parameters inherit from the current state.